# Featured images not showing up

Tags: post-thumbnails

I´m having a strange issue with featured images. Here´s what I did:

1. Added theme support for featured images with `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`
2. Attached a featured image to each post
3. Included the template tag inside the loop: `the_post_thumbnail();`

Strangely the featured image isn´t showing.

However, when I create my own img element it does show up:

```
<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) . '" />
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the issue here? Or where I could start to look for a solution?

I´m not even sure where to start troubleshooting, so all suggestions are welcome!

Comment: your code looks as if you are working with string concatenation (?) - please show the full code of the template file or function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue: I was using a filter in my site specific plugin to remove image attributes. Somehow it also deleted the full image URL.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_img_attributes', 10 );
```

Removing that filter solved the issue.